# Grails 2.4.5: How do you create a Grails REST controller not linked to any domain and an action that returns an object that is not a domain class?

Tags: spring, grails, groovy, grails-controller

I am working on transforming a Grails 2.4.5 application from a website to a web service by transforming most of the service classes to REST Services that will serve a UI.

I encountered an issue when trying to create a simple action to return a list of objects of a simple class, which is a simple DTO class used to only display multiple serialized data coming from multiple domains.

The action inside the controller works fine and returns some JSON data from the Browser as well as from Postman.

However, I can't use Curl with a Bearer Access token to get the data, as it redirects to the home page. I am not sure why there's that redirect.
When I look at the logs, the request with Curl doesn't even enter the controller. I enabled some log.info() message at the first line of the action/method.
I can see that message when the app is launched from the browser and Postman, but not when using CUrl, since the request never gets processed by the action inside the controller.

I am really confused as I am not sure what can be the cause. Any help to point me in a right direction will be helpful.

```
@Secured(['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'])
class ClassController extends RestfulController{

    static responseFormats = ['json']
    static allowedMethods = [actionDTOs  : "GET"]
    static defaultAction = "actionDTOs"

    static scope = "singleton"
        def  actionDTOs() {
        log.info("inside controller /listdtos");
        def listDTOs = getAllDTOs() //private action/method inside controller
        log.info("listDTOs: $listDTOs")
        respond listDTOs, [status: 200]
    }

    private def  getAllDTOs() {
        ..
    }
}
```

```
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
 "/api/v1/listdtos/$size?"(controller:'class', action:'actionDTOs', method: 'GET')

 "/$controller/$action?/$id?" {
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
        }

        /**
        ** This is where the action "**actionDTOs**" is redirected when I try to use CUrl
        ** as well as when the front-end tries to access it.
        ** Why is that I can access the data properly from Browser and Postman?
        **/
        **"/"(controller: 'welcome', action: 'home')**
    }
}
```

```
class listDTOs implements Serializable{
    ...
}
```

Comment: It does not make sense to me that the app behaves differently when the request comes from postman vs curl, but I expect the behavior you are describing has nothing to do with whether or not your controller is associated with a domain class, and doesn't really have anything to do with REST.  If you can share an app that demonstrates the behavior that would be easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: If the `RestfulController` in `class ClassController extends RestfulController` is `grails.rest.RestfulController`, I am a little surprised that works at all since the class is genericized specifically to work with domain classes, and the class has a required constructor which the domain class must be passed to.  See https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/bd7cc10e17d34f20cedce979724f0e3bacd4cdb4/grails-plugin-rest/src/main/groovy/grails/rest/RestfulController.groovy#L42-L51.

Comment: It isn't clear if the `class listDTOs implements Serializable` class that you show has anything to do with the question.  Is that class involved?

Comment: The listDTOs is the main class that has data that I am trying to return. In general, I am trying to see an example of a Restful Grails Controller that isn't tied to the domain. Any such example that goes outside the "Grails convention" of extending a Restful Controller and adding the domain as a parameter will be really helpful. I created an extra controller following the Grails convention of extending RestfulController and it works fine with CUrl. However, ideally, I don't want to have to create extra code.

Comment: "The listDTOs is the main class that has data that I am trying to return. In general, I am trying to see an example of a Restful Grails Controller that isn't tied to the domain." - It depends on what you really want but if by "Restful Grails Controller" you mean a controller that will receive `GET`, `PUT`, `POST` and `DELETE` requests to perform CRUD operations, you can see an example of that by running `grails generate-all com.somepackage.YourDomainClass` which will generate `grails-app/controllers/com/somepackage/YourDomainClass.groovy` which does that.

Comment: What if you don't have a Domain class? For the project that I am working on, they created a Dashboard Controller, not linked to any domain class. The listDTOs class has data from different domain classes that will be displayed on the dashboard. That's the reason for the DTO pattern, hence the listDTOs class. In that scenario, where you can't link that controller to any specific domain as the listDTOs contains some data from more than 5 domain classes, how do you do that in Grails? Or what if you don't have any domain classes and wants to create a Restful Controller with CRUD operations?

Comment: "What if you don't have a Domain class? " - You can write a controller with whatever endpoints in it you like.  It isn't clear what you want the endpoints to do since domain classes aren't involved, but you can put whatever logic you like in the controller.

Comment: I want a REST Controller with an action that will return a list of lidtDTOs through a GET request. To create a Restful Controller, we usually extend the RestfulController or use @Resource on top of our domain. Since not of that applies in my case, what's the workaround to return my non-domain class through a GET request so Grails knows it's a REST Controller not linked to a domain?

Answer (score 0):

To create a Restful Controller, we usually extend the RestfulController or use @Resource on top of our domain> . Since not of that applies in my case, what's the workaround to return my non-domain class through a GET request so Grails knows it's a REST Controller not linked to a domain?

It depends on what you mean by "Restful Controller".

You could have a controller like this:

```
class MyRestfulController {
    static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "PUT", delete: "DELETE"]

    def index() {
         // return a list of all listDto instances
    }

    def show() {
        // return a listDto instances
    }


    def save() {
        // create a listDto instance
    }


    def update() {
        // update a listDto instance
    }

    def delete() {
        // delete a listDto instance
    }
}
```

I know that `listDto` is not a domain class so I can't show code of how to retrieve them or update them but presumably you know how to do that.

**EDIT:**

> I wanted to know if I have to use the default Grails names for the
> action.

You don't.  You could use this:

```
class MyRestfulController {
    static allowedMethods = [persisteANewOne: "POST", makeSomeChangesToOne: "PUT", removeOneOfThem: "DELETE"]

    def showAllOfThem() {
         // return a list of all listDto instances
    }

    def displayOneOfThem() {
        // return a listDto instances
    }


    def persisteANewOne() {
        // create a listDto instance
    }


    def makeSomeChangesToOne() {
        // update a listDto instance
    }

    def removeOneOfThem() {
        // delete a listDto instance
    }
}
```

Then of course in your URL mapping you map whatever urls you like to those actions, as in the previous example.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I wanted to know if I have to use the default Grails names for the action. What if I don't want to use those names? Is there a way to have a different name while somehow letting Grails knows they are the equivalent to the "show" action?

Comment: "I wanted to know if I have to use the default Grails names for the action." - I misunderstood the question.  Apologies.  No, you don't.  You can call the actions almost anything that would be a valid method name in Groovy.  If you don't like `show`, call it `display` or `getSomeInformationAboutAListDto` or whatever you like.

Comment: Will that still be considered a Grails RestController, since at least Grails knows what is meant by "index" and "show" actions? I will try renaming my action to "show" to see if my redirect to the home page with "CUrl" will be resolved. Thank you very much.

Comment: "Will that still be considered a Grails RestController, since at least Grails knows what is meant by "index" and "show" actions?" - Yes.  Whatever your definition of a rest controller is, it shouldn't include the names of methods in the supporting class.